# Error - Premature end of file when you run .jar

Tags: inputstream, saxparseexception

I have an error - SAXParseException: Premature end of file - only when running my .jar file :( When you run through main.class - all excellent.

I tried for a long time to understand the reason, but unfortunately has not found and could not solve the problem.

1. Checked an xml file (notepad ++, total commander) - all ok, no extra characters.
2. Check the encoding of the file, too, everything is OK.
3. Trying to get away from the InputStream, but it did not help me.
4. Created .jar file and using gradle, and standard means of IntelliJ IDEA, has not helped ...

So, friends, I'm confused, if anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

The text of the program, as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Job> getJobsCfg() {
    ArrayList<Job> listJob = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/cfgExecJobs.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        NodeList jobs = doc.getElementsByTagName("job");
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.getLength(); i++) {
            Job job = new Job();
            listJob.add(job);
            Node jobNode = jobs.item(i);
            job.setName(jobNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
            job.setCronTrigger(jobNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("cronTrigger").getNodeValue());
            job.setEnable(jobNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("enable").getNodeValue());
            NodeList params = jobs.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < params.getLength(); j++) {
                if (params.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Param param = new Param();
                    param.setName(params.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
                    param.setValue(params.item(j).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue());
                    job.getListParam().add(param);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listJob;
}
```

I tried without InputStream:

```
    public ArrayList<Job> getJobsCfg() {
    ArrayList<Job> listJob = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse("src/main/resources/config/cfgExecJobs.xml");
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listJob;
}
```